# Why is running any gh cli command on my local machine causing a seg fault/goroutine error?

Tags: node.js, go, github

Running any gh cli command causes this error in my cli. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the gh cli, removed all node.js and npm from my machine, and neither of these things solve the issue.

```
(base) yamini@Yaminis-MacBook-Pro local % gh auth login
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x0 pc=0x1031c6580]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/config.(*Config).Get(0x1038a3548?, {0x140007bfbd8?, 0x30?, 0x10488aea0?})
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/config/config.go:46 +0x30
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/browser.resolveLauncher()
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/browser/browser.go:75 +0x6c
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/browser.New(...)
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/browser/browser.go:32
github.com/cli/cli/v2/internal/browser.New({0x0, 0x0}, {0x1049098a0, 0x14000010018}, {0x1049098a0, 0x14000010020})
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/internal/browser/browser.go:14 +0x58
github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory.newBrowser(0x140003bfdc0?)
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory/default.go:111 +0x50
github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory.New({0x10477ac48, 0x6})
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory/default.go:37 +0x238
main.mainRun()
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/cmd/gh/main.go:64 +0xec
main.main()
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/cmd/gh/main.go:48 +0x1c
(base) yamini@Yaminis-MacBook-Pro local % gh repo create
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x0 pc=0x1031fa580]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/config.(*Config).Get(0x1038d7548?, {0x1400085fbd8?, 0x30?, 0x1048beea0?})
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/config/config.go:46 +0x30
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/browser.resolveLauncher()
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/browser/browser.go:75 +0x6c
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/browser.New(...)
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/browser/browser.go:32
github.com/cli/cli/v2/internal/browser.New({0x0, 0x0}, {0x10493d8a0, 0x140001aa008}, {0x10493d8a0, 0x140001aa010})
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/internal/browser/browser.go:14 +0x58
github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory.newBrowser(0x140000fdce0?)
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory/default.go:111 +0x50
github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory.New({0x1047aec48, 0x6})
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory/default.go:37 +0x238
main.mainRun()
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/cmd/gh/main.go:64 +0xec
main.main()
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/cmd/gh/main.go:48 +0x1c
```

i get the same error with any cli command, not just auth. for example, gh repo create:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x2 addr=0x0 pc=0x100622580]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/config.(*Config).Get(0x100cff548?, {0x140007dfbd8?, 0x30?, 0x101ce6ea0?})
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/config/config.go:46 +0x30
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/browser.resolveLauncher()
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/browser/browser.go:75 +0x6c
github.com/cli/go-gh/pkg/browser.New(...)
    github.com/cli/go-gh@v0.1.1-0.20220817122932-3630ab390fe7/pkg/browser/browser.go:32
github.com/cli/cli/v2/internal/browser.New({0x0, 0x0}, {0x101d658a0, 0x140001aa008}, {0x101d658a0, 0x140001aa010})
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/internal/browser/browser.go:14 +0x58
github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory.newBrowser(0x140000f7ce0?)
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory/default.go:111 +0x50
github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory.New({0x101bd6c48, 0x6})
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/pkg/cmd/factory/default.go:37 +0x238
main.mainRun()
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/cmd/gh/main.go:64 +0xec
main.main()
    github.com/cli/cli/v2/cmd/gh/main.go:48 +0x1c
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a segfault and almost all segfaults on working hardware are bugs (in some software).  It looks like there's some issue in `gh` that prevents it from initializing its configuration object properly, and then it tries to dereference an invalid pointer.

You should open an issue at https://github.com/cli/cli, filling out the issue template and explaining anything you've done that might be relevant.  For example, if your repository is missing its `.git/config` file, or you do (or don't) have any unusual configuration settings, you should mention those.